# Difference between Platform::String and std::string

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I know C++ but I am pretty new to VC++, I was going through the code of VC++ and found on many places Platform::String is only used, no use of std::string.
Is there any specific advantage of Platform::String? How Platform::String and std::string are different?

Comment: `Platform::String` is a non-standard extension by Microsoft so non-Microsoft compilers and libraries are not required to support it - and, in practice, most vendors do not support it.   `std::string` is part of the C++ standard, so will be supported by ALL vendors that provide a C++ hosted implementation (compiler and library).      If you're happy to be locked into using Microsoft toochains, then use `Platform::String`.   If you care at all about portability to other toolchains or host systems, then use `std::string`.

Comment: I'ts not a simple extension. You may have to use it for managed code. After all, if one considers using Platform::String is locked anyway to Windows. Portability is feasible only with simpler applications, not with applications that deal a lot with OS specific features like the Runtime API. std::string cannot be used in place of std::string, when it comes to APIs like that, however the whole C++/CX is now obsolete.

Comment: ok. understood. Thanks Peter and Michael for your valuable comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With reference of [Strings (C++/CX)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cppcx/strings-c-cx?view=vs-2019), when you are dealing with windows run time classes or any component then **Platform::String** is best option otherwise use std::string only for any manipulation or string handling.

Comment: As this page also says

The `Platform::String` Class provides methods for several common string operations, but it's not designed to be a full-featured string class. In your C++ module, use standard C++ string types such as wstring for any significant text processing, and then convert the final result to `Platform::String^` before you pass it to or from a public interface. 

**So what is so special in `Platform::String` that microsoft opted to create it rather than using std::string?**

Comment: C++/CX is deprecated in favor of C++/WinRT anyway.

Comment: @ChiragAcharya Nothing special in Plateform::String rather i would say Plateform::String is more limited when its come to string handling. Only thing Plateform::String  makes special is bonding with Windows plateform. Its wrapper arroung HSTRING which will help you to deal with functions like: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/WinRT/functions

Comment: Thanks Santosh and Michael for your help.
As there is only one answer accepting it.